# Using a desktop with Ubuntu 14.10...upper right corner says battery is charged 100%, why? (there is no battery)

Tags: battery, 14.10

I've done no modification to the system and I onky use apt-get update/upgrade. Nothing special like dist-upgrade or using beta packages. Should be standard stuff.

This happened a couple weeks ago too. I booted up, it says there's a battery. I restarted because I thought it was weird, it went back to saying AC power on next boot.

Today it's back, but I've restarted several times and update/upgraded, but it's staying this time.

Here's a little screenshot of it:

[image]

Comment: Click the icon, choose Power Settings and in Show battery status in the menu bar switch it to Never. It may be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Notice the little keyboard symbol next to it?

It's the battery status of your wireless keyboard.

If you don't have a wireless keyboard, it's a bug. Report it against [`indicator-power`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-power).